# Print Array in required order

Tags: c, arrays, string

Im a new programmer

I am have an char array M = "something",
and I want to print in this way

```
t
eth
methi
omethin
something
```

can any one help me in the logic to print in this way using loops.

I have used this code so far, but shows Segmentation error, can any body help me out where I have gone wrong.

```
main() {
    int i, j, k, m, n;
    char a[] = "Something";

    n = sizeof(a) - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < (n/2) + 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n - i; j++)
            printf(" ");
        for (m = (n/2) - i; !(m >= (n/2)); m--)
            printf("%c",a[m]);
        for (k = (n/2);k <= (n/2) + i; k++)
            printf("%c", a[k]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the precision speficier in the `printf()` format string (like `printf("%.*s\n", nchars, a + start);`) may be helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C program i created , hope this helps.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
     char *str,*p1,*p2;
     int count=0;
     str="something";
     p1=str;                     //points to the first element of the string.  
     while(*(str+1)!='\0')
         str++;
     p2=str;                    //points to the last element of the string.

     while(*p1!='\0')
     {
         if(p1==p2)
             printf("%c\n",*p1);
         if(p1>p2)
         {
             while(p2<=p1)
             {
                 printf("%c",*p2);
                 p2++;
                 count++;
             }
             p2=p2-(count);
             count=0;
                printf("\n");
         }

         p1++;           // move to right.
         p2--;           // move to left.
     }          
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Time complexity of this algorithm would be **O(n^2)**

Answer (score 4):

Linear solution (note the string must be modifiable)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 char array[] = "something";
 char * str = array;
 int size = strlen(str);
 int i=size/2;
 if(size%2==0)i--;
 for(;i>=0;i--){
    char c = str[size-i];   
    str[size-i]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",str+i);
    str[size-i]=c;
 }  
}
```

I remember i had a homework like this when I was learning c :)

Update:

As Jonathan Leffler pointed out, without modifying the string itself, we can print by passing the string length to printf function. (I didn't know the `%.*s` specifier :)) Well it shows we can learn even from a basic simple problems :) Thanks Jonathan. This makes the code more elegant and compact.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void print_string(const char *string)
{
  int size = strlen(string),i;
  for (i = (size - 1) / 2; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d:%d: %.*s\n", i, size-2*i, size-2*i, string+i);
}
int main()
{
  char * a = "something";
  print_string(a);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do it without modifying the string, using the `%.*s` notation to specify the length to print.

Comment: Try: `void print_string(const char *string) { int size = strlen(string); for (int i = (size - 1) / 2; i >= 0; i--) printf("%d:%d: %.*s\n", i, size-2*i, size-2*i, string+i); }` — wrapped as a function.  Tested on 'something', 'anything', 'nothing', 'annual', 'prime', 'four', 'tri', 'bi', '1', '' and it seems to work OK (but only because `size` is a signed `int`!).

Comment: thanks Jonathan for the nice suggestion. I updated the answer with your suggestion